# trim string after number

Tags: c#, string, url

i need to adjust my code so that it will trim the url after the number. 
for example, i want everything after List=36 removed. letters and special characters are the only potential characters that could follow the List number.  so i just want to trim the url when it reads a letter or special character after the list number. thanks.

examples of current urls that are capture on submit

```
https://portal.test/sites/test/testabc/Lists/TEST/DispFormSort.aspx?List=36caab7e%2D2234%2D4981%2D8225%%2Easpx

https://portal.test/sites/test/testabc/Lists/TEST/DispFormSort.aspx?List=36,http://portal.test/testabc/Lists/TEST/AllItems.aspx
```

url i want captured on submit:

https://portal.test.com/sites/test/testabc/Lists/RFC/DispFormSort.aspx?List=36

my current code for the method that captures the url:

```
    public static string GenerateShortUrl(SPList list, int itemId)
    {
        try
        {
            var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
            var itemUrl = string.Empty;

            if (item.File == null)
                itemUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/" + list.Forms[PAGETYPE.PAGE_DISPLAYFORM].Url + "?ID=" + item.ID;
            else
                itemUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/" + item.Url;

            var generatedShortedUrl = GetShortUrl(itemUrl);

            return generatedShortedUrl;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utilities.WriteError(ex.ToString());

            throw new SPException("An error occurred while attempting to shorten a URL.", ex);
        }
    }
```

---

```
     private static string GetShortUrl(string itemUrl)
        {
            var shortId = Utilities.GenerateHash(itemUrl);
            var shortenerUrl = string.Empty;

            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                    var farm = SPAdministrationWebApplication.Local;
                    using (var site = farm.Sites[0])
                    {
                        using (var web = site.RootWeb)
                        {
                            if (!web.Properties.ContainsKey("LiebrandUrlShortener"))
                                throw new SPException(SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:liebrandurlshortener,CannotFindUrl", "liebrandurlshortener", web.Language));

                            var urlList = web.Lists[SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:liebrandurlshortener,StorageName", "liebrandurlshortener", web.Language)];

                            var query = new SPQuery();
                            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + shortId + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

                            var items = urlList.GetItems(query);
                            if (items.Count == 0)
                            {

                                var urlListItem = urlList.Items.Add();
                                urlListItem["Title"] = shortId;
                                urlListItem["RedirectTo"] = itemUrl;

                                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                urlListItem.Update();
                                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                            }

                            shortenerUrl = web.Properties["LiebrandUrlShortener"];
                        }
                    }
            });

            return shortenerUrl + "/" + shortId;
        }

        public static string GenerateShortUrl(string longUrl)
        {
            return GetShortUrl(longUrl);
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to capture everything until ?List=[number].

You can use this Regex:

```
Regex.Match(str, @"^.*\?List=\d+").Value
```

Comment: You can do this even if the base is not the same (capture everything until `?` and push it back out with the updated `List` value

Answer (score 0):

```
 string url = "https://portal.test.com/sites/test/testabc/Lists/RFC/DispFormSort.aspx?List=36caab7e%2D2234%2D4981%2D8225%%2E.aspx";

 Regex regex = new Regex(@"^.*List=\d+");
 Match match = regex.Match(url);

 if (match.Success)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
 }
```

**EDIT:** Changed code, I thought he had to extract only the number.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the hard way is the most straightforward way. The Regex-based answers will return incorrect values for URLs that are not in the expected format.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inputString = @"https://portal.test/sites/test/testabc/Lists/TEST/DispFormSort.aspx?List=36caab7e%2D2234%2D4981%2D8225%%2Easpx";

        //TEST CASES:

        //string inputString = @"https://portal.test/sites/test/testabc/Lists/TEST/DispFormSort.aspx?SomeParam=36caab7e%2D2234%2D4981%2D8225%%2Easpx";
        //should return null

        //string inputString = @"https://portal.test/sites/test/testabc/Lists/TEST/DispFormSort.aspx?SomeParam=nih543&List=786yui";
        //should return https://portal.test/sites/test/testabc/Lists/TEST/DispFormSort.aspx?786

        //string inputString = @"https://portal.test/sites/test/testabc/Lists/TEST/DispFormSort.aspx?";
        //should return null

        //string inputString = @"https://portal.test/sites/test/testabc/Lists/TEST/DispFormSort.aspx";
        //should return null

        string result = GetShortenedListURL(inputString);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static string GetShortenedListURL(string InputString)
    {
        //Split URL into address and parameter tokens
        var tokens = InputString.Split('?');
        if (tokens.Length > 1)
        {
            var urlParams = tokens[1].Split('&');
            const string listStarter = "LIST=";

            //Loop through parameters looking for one that begins with List
            foreach (var param in urlParams)
            {
                if (param.ToUpperInvariant().StartsWith(listStarter))
                {
                    //Found the right parameter, now look for a contiguous string of numbers
                    for (int numCounter = listStarter.Length; numCounter < param.Length; numCounter++)
                    {
                        if (!Char.IsDigit(param[numCounter]))
                        {
                            if (numCounter > listStarter.Length)
                            {
                                return tokens[0] + "?" + param.Substring(listStarter.Length, numCounter - listStarter.Length);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your input. i just displayed all of my method code. should i place your forloop inside the if statement?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the method does because i can't tell what the SPList class does. However, it seems all you need to do is change the `var generatedShortedUrl = GetShortUrl(itemUrl);` call to call `GetShortenedListURL` instead. You'd have to check for null (which means it couldn't find **List=** in the URL) and decide if you want to throw an exception or do something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use regex to do this. As you said letters and special characters are the only potential characters that could follow the List number, my regex is picking up everything until ?List=[number] and any letters and special characters till it finds a digit or character that should not be picked up

```
Regex.Match(url, @"^.*\?List=\d+[A-Za-z._%+-]*+").Value
```

Try testing this here: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I prefer LINQ:

```
string url = @"https://portal.test/...";
string flag = "List=";
int flagIndex = url.IndexOf(flag) + flag.Length;
string shortUrl = new string(url.TakeWhile((ch, index) => 
                          index < flagIndex || char.IsDigit(ch)).ToArray());
```